# apply lookup on delimited values and join back in pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a data frame with a column having a delimited country code :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Division':['A', 'B', 'C'], 
                  'Country_code': ['US, UK, SG', 'BZ, UAE, UK', 'CA, UK, IND'],
                  'Zone': ['Red', 'Green, 'Red'] })
```

And I have country_df

```
df_country = pd.DataFrame({'Code':['US', 'UK', 'SG', 'BZ', 'IND', 'CA'], 
                  'Country': ['United States', 'United Kingdome', 'Sigapore', 'Brazil', 'India', 'CANADA']})
```

Now I want to replace country_code with country name

How I can do this using pandas

I want final output as :

```
Division  Country_code                              Zone
A         United states, United Kingdome, Sigapore   Red  
B         Brazil, NA, United kingdome                Green
C         Canada, United Kingdome, INDIA             Red
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First get list of all missing codes by [`numpy.setdiff1d`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html) with `Series` created by [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) and [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
missing = (np.setdiff1d(df['Country_code'].str.split(', ', expand=True).stack(), 
                        df_country['Code'])).tolist()
print (missing)
['UAE']
```

Create dictionary for mapping by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and [`Series.to_dict`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_dict.html) and then map splitted values by `get` for possible create default value if no match, last join together:

```
d = df_country.set_index('Code')['Country'].to_dict()
df['Country_code'] = [', '.join(d.get(y, 'NA') 
                                        for y in x.split(', ')) for x in df['Country_code']]
print (df)
  Division                              Country_code   Zone
0        A  United States, United Kingdome, Sigapore    Red
1        B               Brazil, NA, United Kingdome  Green
2        C            CANADA, United Kingdome, India    Red
```

Comment: Hey, It's working exactly as I wanted. However can you please suggest any way where I can also store a unique list of country code  for which country name is not available df_country?

Comment: @RajeshMhatre - Yop, give em a sec.